# I have been exercising today/this week

Tags: meaning-in-context

Am I correct about this?

"I have been exercising today" probably means just once today, with a duration.

"I have been exercising this week" means I have exercised multiple times this week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but only because of the meaning and connotations of the word "exercising".

On the balance of possibilities "I have been exercising" this week could mean once or it could mean on several occasions. But my knowledge of how long and how often most exercise sessions are would lead me to imagine that this meant "on several occasions"

On the other hand the same knowledge would lead me to understand "I have been exercising today" differently.

Comment: Differently how? "You mean "I have been exercising today" means once?

Comment: Yes, once. But note that this interpretation depends on my understanding of the nature of exercise, not an application of a grammatical rule.

Comment: " I have been exercising" this week could mean once". Other natives disagree, that is quite confusing.

Comment: It could mean once.  It probably doesn't.